# How to lazy evaluate variables used in foreach loops in Chef Infra

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to setup a Chef Infra recipe where the same recipe installs some software and makes some post-install registry changes. Because the registry keys this software creates at installation can have random GUID-based names, I have opted to get the list of keys using the "registry_get_keys" method after the installation completes to get the names of the subkeys and then use a for-each loop to perform the registry changes under each subkey.

However, I am running into the issue where the recipe fails to compile because the registry keys it needs to  look for don't exist yet.

I tried to place the assignment of registry_get_keys to a variable in a ruby_block but that causes the issue of me not being able to pass the variable values to the next resource and as a result, the for-each loop fails.

This is a simplified test case that illustrates the problem:

```
# Simulate installer creating registry keys with random GUIDs at HKCU\Environment
registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\1" do
    recursive true
end
registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\2" do
    recursive true
end
registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\3" do
    recursive true
end

keys = registry_get_subkeys('HKCU\Environment\Test')

keys.each do |key|
    registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\#{key}\\Subkey" do
        values [{
            :name => "SOMENAME",
            :type => :string,
            :data => "SOMEDATA"
        }]
        action :create
    end
end
```

When I try to execute this, recipe obviously fails to compile since the "Test" subkey does not exist yet.

```
Chef Infra Client, version 17.10.0
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
Infra Phase starting
[2023-05-05T12:59:18] INFO: *** Chef Infra Client 17.10.0 ***
[2023-05-05T12:59:18] INFO: Platform: x64-mingw32
[2023-05-05T12:59:18] INFO: Chef-client pid: 32020

[2023-05-05T12:59:24] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2023-05-05T12:59:24] WARN: Original Run List: []
[2023-05-05T12:59:24] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[test-cookbook::default]]
[2023-05-05T12:59:24] INFO: Run List is [recipe[test-cookbook::default]]
[2023-05-05T12:59:24] INFO: Run List expands to [test-cookbook::default]
[2023-05-05T12:59:24] INFO: Starting Chef Infra Client Run for user
[2023-05-05T12:59:24] INFO: Running start handlers
[2023-05-05T12:59:24] INFO: Start handlers complete.
Resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test-cookbook::default"]
[2023-05-05T12:59:25] INFO: Loading cookbooks [test-cookbook@0.1.0]
[2023-05-05T12:59:25] INFO: Skipping removal of obsoleted cookbooks from the cache
Synchronizing cookbooks:
[2023-05-05T12:59:25] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb in the cache.
  - test-cookbook (0.1.0)
Installing cookbook gem dependencies:
Compiling cookbooks...


Loading Chef InSpec profile files:
Loading Chef InSpec input files:
Loading Chef InSpec waiver files:

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Win32RegKeyMissing
------------------------------------
Registry key HKCU\Environment\Test does not exist

Cookbook Trace: (most recent call first)
----------------------------------------
  c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb:20:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb:

 13:  registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\2" do
 14:    recursive true
 15:  end
 16:  registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\3" do
 17:    recursive true

 18:  end
 19:
 20>> keys = registry_get_subkeys('HKCU\Environment\Test')
 21:
 22:  keys.each do |key|
 23:    registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\#{key}\\Subkey" do
 24:            values [{
 25:                    :name => "SOMENAME",
 26:                    :type => :string,
 27:                    :data => "SOMEDATA"
 28:            }]
 29:            action :create

System Info:
------------
chef_version=17.10.0
platform=windows
platform_version=10.0.19045
ruby=ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x64-mingw32]
program_name=C:/opscode/chef-workstation/modules/chef/../../bin/chef-client
executable=C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2023-05-05T12:59:26] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2023-05-05T12:59:26] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Infra Phase failed. 0 resources updated in 07 seconds
[2023-05-05T12:59:26] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2023-05-05T12:59:26] FATAL: --------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-05T12:59:26] FATAL: PLEASE PROVIDE THE CONTENTS OF THE stacktrace.out FILE (above) IF YOU FILE A BUG REPORT
[2023-05-05T12:59:26] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-05T12:59:26] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Win32RegKeyMissing: Registry key HKCU\Environment\Test does not exist
```

Next, I tried placing the registry_get_keys part in a ruby_block to prevent it's execution in the compile phase:

```
# Simulate installer creating registry keys with random GUIDs at HKCU\Environment
registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\1" do
    recursive true
end
registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\2" do
    recursive true
end
registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\3" do
    recursive true
end

ruby_block 'get_keys' do
    block do
        keys = registry_get_subkeys('HKCU\Environment\Test')
    end
end

keys.each do |key|
    registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\#{key}\\Subkey" do
        values [{
            :name => "SOMENAME",
            :type => :string,
            :data => "SOMEDATA"
        }]
        action :create
    end
end
```

This results in the following error because "keys" isn't defined:

```
Chef Infra Client, version 17.10.0
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
Infra Phase starting
[2023-05-05T13:09:22] INFO: *** Chef Infra Client 17.10.0 ***
[2023-05-05T13:09:22] INFO: Platform: x64-mingw32
[2023-05-05T13:09:22] INFO: Chef-client pid: 11616

[2023-05-05T13:09:29] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] WARN: Original Run List: []
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[test-cookbook::default]]
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Run List is [recipe[test-cookbook::default]]
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Run List expands to [test-cookbook::default]
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Starting Chef Infra Client Run for user
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Running start handlers
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Start handlers complete.
Resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test-cookbook::default"]
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Loading cookbooks [test-cookbook@0.1.0]
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Skipping removal of obsoleted cookbooks from the cache
Synchronizing cookbooks:
[2023-05-05T13:09:29] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb in the cache.
  - test-cookbook (0.1.0)
Installing cookbook gem dependencies:
Compiling cookbooks...


Loading Chef InSpec profile files:
Loading Chef InSpec input files:
Loading Chef InSpec waiver files:

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

NameError
---------
undefined local variable or method `keys' for cookbook: test-cookbook, recipe: default :Chef::Recipe

Cookbook Trace: (most recent call first)
----------------------------------------
  c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb:26:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test-cookbook/recipes/default.rb:

 19:
 20:  ruby_block 'get_keys' do
 21:    block do
 22:            keys = registry_get_subkeys('HKCU\Environment\Test')
 23:    end
 24:  end
 25:
 26>> keys.each do |key|
 27:    registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\#{key}\\Subkey" do
 28:            values [{
 29:                    :name => "SOMENAME",
 30:                    :type => :string,
 31:                    :data => "SOMEDATA"
 32:            }]
 33:            action :create
 34:    end
 35:  end

System Info:
------------
chef_version=17.10.0
platform=windows
platform_version=10.0.19045
ruby=ruby 3.0.3p157 (2021-11-24 revision 3fb7d2cadc) [x64-mingw32]
program_name=C:/opscode/chef-workstation/modules/chef/../../bin/chef-client
executable=C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2023-05-05T13:09:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2023-05-05T13:09:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Infra Phase failed. 0 resources updated in 08 seconds
[2023-05-05T13:09:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/users/user/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2023-05-05T13:09:30] FATAL: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-
[2023-05-05T13:09:30] FATAL: PLEASE PROVIDE THE CONTENTS OF THE stacktrace.out FILE (above) IF YOU FILE A BUG REPORT
[2023-05-05T13:09:30] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-05-05T13:09:30] FATAL: NameError: undefined local variable or method `keys' for cookbook: test-cookbook, recipe: default :Chef::Recipe
```

How can I force Chef Infra to not evaluate the "keys" variable until the convergence phase during a run? I've also tried placing the registry_key resource in a ruby_block but that doesn't seem to be a valid or possible use.

Answer (score 0):

By design, any Ruby code within recipes is evaluated during "compile" phase. So the below runs before resources have converged.

```rb
keys = registry_get_subkeys('HKCU\Environment\Test')

keys.each do |key|
```

There is a `compile_time` directive to resources, which will allow the resources to converge during compile time. So we could set `compile_time true` in the resource.

Like below:

```rb
[1, 2, 3].each do |guid|
  registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\#{guid}" do
    compile_time true
    recursive true
  end
end

# This will work as above resource created the expected keys
keys = registry_get_subkeys('HKCU\Environment\Test')

node['cookbook1']['guids'].each do |guid|
  registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\Test\\#{guid}\\Subkey" do
    values [{
      :name => "SOMENAME",
      :type => :string,
      :data => "SOMEDATA"
    }]
    action :create
  end
end
```

*However, if its possible to have attributes for the keys and GUIDs*, we can control and manage the registry keys without having to query the registry.

Example:

**attributes\default.rb**:

```rb
default['cookbook1']['env_key'] = 'Test'
default['cookbook1']['guids'] = [1, 2, 3]
```

**recipes\default.rb**:

```rb
node['cookbook1']['guids'].each do |guid|
  registry_key "HKCU\\Environment\\#{node['cookbook1']['env_key']}\\#{guid}\\Subkey" do
    values [{
      :name => "SOMENAME",
      :type => :string,
      :data => "SOMEDATA"
    }]
    action :create
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Is it possible to install software (e.g. through windows_package resource) during the compile phase? Is that even a "best practice"? The registry keys are created during a software install so I have no way of knowing what the GUIDs would be to convert to using attributes. I am only creating them manually here to provide an easy-to-reproduce example. I suppose the only other option would be to convert this to use a powershell script?

Comment: It is possible to use the `compile_time` property on any Chef resource. Compile phase is for compiling, but if a use case necessitates running this in compile phase, then I'd pick this over running a powershell script.

Comment: The other option is using a custom-resource which will be evaluated at converge phase (when the action is run) or using a lazy evaluation if it need a package resource to run before. Moving everything to compile phase can be a headache to debug later and should be avoided when possible.